# DDD - What is a complex domain?

Tags: domain-driven-design

It is often said that DDD (Domain-driven Design) is better suited for complex domains instead of simpler ones.

What characterizes a complex domain? (please be more specific than *"it has complex business rules"*);

Which are examples of complex domains?

How can I classify a domain as complex (i.e. suitable for DDD) or not?

Comment: I would say that not just for *complex domains* but also for *ambitious projects that aim to have a long life*. The second statement ignores the complexity.

Answer (score 6):

From my experience 3 most important thing that makes your domain complex:

**Size**

Big domains tends to increase complexity. Handling and coordinate a lot of things is always hard.

**Rules and invariants**

Domains (even domains with just a couple of bounded context) might have a lot of domain rules and invariants and/or a lot of nuances in its use cases and process. This increase complexity. Rules that spam a lot of changes in a entity  or inter-domains events are often the *complex business rules*.

**Context**

Context complexity is hard to explain wihtout a example. Let's put in the table a context complexity related to a entity named `Product`.

Depending of context; a entity could means different things in your domain. A `Product` entity doesn't means the same for Factory context, Marketing context, Sales context, PostSales support context, etc.

If the data, user cases, process, behaviour, etc related to `Product` entity, in every context, are very different the complexity increase a lot even when you just have a handful of context and entities. This usually means that you have many `Product` entities (one in every context) even if all of them are supported by the same persistence store (in case of ER store, the same table/s).

Answer (score 1):

There is no unique definition of complexity, but there is a useful description in Vaughn Vernon book ([Implementing Domain Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321834577)) : Table 1.1 The DDD Scorecard.

He describes the project with different criteria, for example : a complex project is going to change often (new features and it will be hardly to anticipate), you don't fully understand the domain (or there is a lot of ambiguity that you need to discuss with business expert), the size as @jlvaquero said (number of feature/rules/richness of the language...).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, one sign of complex domains is degree of hardness of creating and maintaining Ubiquitous Language.

As the vocabulary, phrase, and terminology become more diverse, creation of UL become more difficult. This confirms the complexity of the domain.